# How to create a UEFI Ubuntu flash drive

Tags: dual-boot

I have windows 10 on my PC after switching from Ubuntu MATE but I realized that windows 10 is only good for programming in java and that's it. So I tried and dual boot Ubuntu mate and windows 10(uefi) but there was no option to install alongside windows boot manager. I didn't want to go dicking around the partitions because I am not a pro. I later learned I needed to make uefi Ubuntu bootable flashdrive. None of the guides are clear. So how do you do it?
Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im dualbooting windows 10 and ubuntu 16.04. but i use grub2 as a boot manager, and if i mess up i usually just use boot-repair. you can do more than program java in windows. i haven't come across something i could not do in windows, but some things are easier in ubuntu.
your questions already has been answered.
[How to create UEFI-only bootable USB live media?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media)